# Jupyter notebook issues -Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

```
jupyter notebook or jupyter-notebook
```

gives error --> Script file 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py' is not present.

```
    Don't have \.jupyter folder in %users%
    No shortcut in windows startup created.
    machine details: Windows 10 - 64 bit
    conda version --> 4.6.11
    Python version -->3.7.3
    jupyter version --> 4.4.0
```

pls help me resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not installed correctly yet how have you installed jupyter. Since you have anaconda try this first in your cmd.

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

Then run `jupyter notebook` again in your cmd and see how it goes

Comment: Thank you for an instant answer and help.

Comment: all good if I have answered your question just marked my answer as accepted so in future it will help others

Comment: but this also didnt help: i get the error : ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.35.6-py37_0'. Rolling back: Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package conda-forge::jupyterlab-0.35.6-py37_0
location of failed script: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\.jupyterlab-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:
stderr:
return code: 105

Comment: How strange, could you try opening the Anaconda navigator and install jupyter from there?

Comment: Jupyter is already installed in navigator, i tried updating/upgrading, nothing happened. earlier command and few more which i tried has upgraded conda version to latest though.

Comment: If i update notebook by conda install notebook, gives error InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\notebook-5.7.8-py37_1.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nCan't create '\\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\pkgs\\notebook-5.7.8-py37_1\\Lib\\site-packages\\notebook\\static\\components\\MathJax\\extensions\\a11y\\invalid_keypress.mp3'")